# PubSub with spring: know the message is publish or not?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub

My publisher code look like this:

```
public abstract class PubSubPublisher {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PubSubPublisher.class);

    private final PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate;

    protected PubSubPublisher(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        this.pubSubTemplate = pubSubTemplate;
    }

    protected abstract String topic(String topicName);

    public void publish(String topicName, String message) throws StatusRuntimeException {
        LOGGER.info("Publishing to topic [{}]. Message: [{}]", topicName, message);
        pubSubTemplate.publish(topicName, message);
    }

}
```

My Component

```
@Component
public class HelloPubSubPublisher extends PubSubPublisher {

    @Autowired
    public HelloPubSubPublisher(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) throws StatusRuntimeException{
        super(pubSubTemplate);
    }

    @Override
    protected String topic(String topicName) {
        return topicName;
    }

}
```

Now on my service layer how do i get weather i successful publish the message to topic or not, note all the google api are async which i am using.

```
try {
    publisher.publish(topicName, payload);
}catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("ioException occured: "+e);
    throw new TopicNotFoundException();
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to capture the any error, program cursor is not going into the catch block.

Ultimately, I wanted to know weather the code is push the message into topic if not then I have to log it and throw that error to client, which is not happen with my current code with proper exception handling.

Any help or guidance is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can check that on the google cloud platform dashboard PubSub > Subscriptions > Click on one subscription > View messages

Answer (score 2):

Using the function `publish()` you should be able to capture a `future` where you can check if the message was published or not.

You have an example of it on [Google's PubSub documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publish):

```
// Once published, returns a server-assigned message id (unique within the topic)
ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);

// Add an asynchronous callback to handle success / failure
ApiFutures.addCallback(
    future,
    new ApiFutureCallback<String>() {

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable instanceof ApiException) {
          ApiException apiException = ((ApiException) throwable);
          // details on the API exception
          System.out.println(apiException.getStatusCode().getCode());
          System.out.println(apiException.isRetryable());
        }
        System.out.println("Error publishing message : " + message);
      }

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(String messageId) {
        // Once published, returns server-assigned message ids (unique within the topic)
        System.out.println(messageId);
      }
    },
    MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
```